# objective C : Stop loading TableView after leaving ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two UIViewController A and B with navigationController.On page A, after calling APIs create/update UITableView. After selecting a cell on A, control goes to B. Also on B page APIs are called and renders tableView. On B page APIs have some images so it takes time in rendering tableview. After calling API & before rendering the table view, if I tap back button, control goes to A page and hit APIs of A. But I noticed that table view in B page still tries to render. So sometimes my App crashes with reason "DataSource is not set".

Comment: It would be useful to see some of your code, eg, how you are handling the (presumably async) networking calls & responses, & implementing the tableView updates

Answer (score 0):

When you leave(tap back) ViewController , it must be dealloced, it seems to be a memory leak bug, so to check this add this code to B ViewController

```
deinit {
   print(1)
}
```

If everything is ok, it will print "1", if not, check in B controller - Have you some blocks(closers)?,
Is in blocks used "self", if yes - do you use "weak self" ?

```
__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
```

that must resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I added this code 
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"1");
}

it printed, after rendering table of B controllerView.

Comment: I am also trying  to disable BACK button self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO but this code is not working. but i am able to hide BACK button from this code self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES.

Comment: I think as ViewController was dealloced, you have no need to cancel your request (if it is asyc), but if you need so you can try to timeout your request in deinit method

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not create weak refference to your imageview for lazy loading images in cellForRowAt indexpath method. Try to use below code in datasource method it will help for you.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CustomTableviewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
__weak UIImageView *weakImageView = cell.yourImageView;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    weakImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]]];
});
return cell;
}
```